# I have a problem with the syntax code of exception inside the for loop in oracle sql server

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to add exception when My manager counting equals 0. But there is an syntax error with my code and I don't know what to do.

the error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of
>   the following:
>
> ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null    pragma
>   raise return select update while with       <<    continue
>   close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback    savepoint set
>   sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge    json_exists json_value
>   json_query json_object json_array
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

```
FOR l in c LOOP
select count(*) into variable
    from table where job = 'Manager'
    and condition;


    if SQL%NOTFOUND
EXCEPTION
    then 
        RAISE e_my_exception;
    end if;
    //the code to check salary of employee greater than president or lower than 100 is here //

    WHEN e_my_exception THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR!!! One department has no manager ');  
END LOOP;
```

I expected to print out 'ERROR!!! One department has no manager ' but instead there is an error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are implementing it in a wrong format, it is are as follows ...

```
DECLARE 
   <declarations section> 
BEGIN 
   <executable command(s)> //your logic
EXCEPTION 
   <exception handling> 
END;
```

and loop are implemented this way ...just for example

```
DECLARE 
   i number(1); 
   j number(1); 
BEGIN 
   FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP 
         dbms_output.put_line('i is: '|| i ); 
   END loop; 
END;
```

and for handling exception refer this...

```
    DECLARE 
   c_id customers.id%type := 8; 
   c_name customerS.Name%type; 
   c_addr customers.address%type; 
BEGIN 
   SELECT  name, address INTO  c_name, c_addr 
   FROM customers 
   WHERE id = c_id;  
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Name: '||  c_name); 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Address: ' || c_addr); 

EXCEPTION 
   WHEN no_data_found THEN 
      dbms_output.put_line('No such customer!'); 
   WHEN others THEN 
      dbms_output.put_line('Error!'); 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not handling exceptions correctly. I suggest the following:

```
FOR l in c LOOP
  BEGIN
    select count(*)
      into variable
      from table where job = 'Manager'
      and condition;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR!!! One department has no manager');  
  END;
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "oracle sql server" (as your title suggests). It is either "Oracle" or "(Microsoft) SQL Server". Code you posted is Oracle, so I'd suggest you to fix the title.

---

Now, your question: as count(*) won't work "no data found" nor "sql%notfound" when there's nothing there (but 0 as a result) - see a demonstration:

```
SQL> select count(*) from dual where 1 = 2;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```

then you could do something like this:

```
FOR l in c LOOP
  begin
    select count(*) into variable
      from table where job = 'Manager'
      and condition;

    if variable = 0 then
       RAISE e_my_exception;
    end if;
    --the code to check salary of employee greater than president or lower than 100 is here //

  exception
    WHEN e_my_exception THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR!!! One department has no manager ');  
END LOOP;
```

Such a code would display the message (if your tool supports it), but loop would continue *looping*, i.e. your code wouldn't stop.

---

Though, as you aren't actually *raising* anything, a simpler option would be

```
FOR l in c LOOP
    select count(*) into variable
      from table where job = 'Manager'
      and condition;

    if variable = 0 then
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR!!! One department has no manager ');  
    end if;
    --the code to check salary of employee greater than president or lower than 100 is here //
END LOOP;
```